# Bash shell: How to assign a bc calculated result to a variable and print it out?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to replicate the code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bc-command-linux-examples/)[image]

For whatever reason, it doesn't work on my computer. The outout, rather than the numercal value, is the command itself.

```
apple$ x='echo "var=500;var%=7;var"|bc'
apple$ $x
"var=500;var%=7;var"|bc
```

I would like to know why is that. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source uses backticks (`` ` ``) to indicate command substitution. The command specified within the backticks is executed, and the result is put in its place. In this case, it is a simple variable assignment, so the result of the command is assigned to the variable.

This is easy to see with the `-x` option to bash:

```
$ x=`echo "var=500;var%=7;var"|bc`
++ echo 'var=500;var%=7;var'
++ bc
+ x=3
```

Instead of the backtick characters, you have used single quotes. Single quotes instruct the shell to keep the literal value and not apply any kind of processing to its contents. As a result, the command is assigned as-is to the variable. This is the corresponding `-x` output:

```
$ x='echo "var=500;var%=7;var"|bc'
+ x='echo "var=500;var%=7;var"|bc'
```

Lastly, to print out the variable contents, you should use `echo` or `printf`. When the value of 'x' is 3, running `$x` would give you a `-bash: 3: command not found` error message. Running `$x` worked in your case only because the `echo` command was part of the variable contents.

Comment: good catch on them missing the `echo` in the command there

Answer (score 3):

As Haxiel noted, instead of the backtick characters, you have most likely used single quotes. But better than using backticks (`` ` ``) I suggest you use `$()`. Backticks are deprecated and `$()` is POSIX compatible.

In your example you could do:

```
x=$(echo "var=500;var%=7;var" | bc)
echo "$x"
```

Or in a one liner:

```
echo "var=500;var%=7;var" | bc
```

Comment: You are right @they thanks for pointing it out. I will correct it.